# Meaning of Further

Tags: meaning

What does *further* mean in a sentence like:

> We further describe the evaluation protocol.

Does it mean "we then describe the evaluation protocol"?

Comment: Hi Shayan. Can you give us more context? -  because otherwise the sentence is ambiguous and you might get an answer that doesn't fit the actual sentence in the text you're looking at.

Comment: Suppose that in a paper, I want to say that after the beforementioned thing, we describe the evaluation protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the evaluation protocol has been described to some extent and the authors are now going to describe it some more.

> **Further** *adverb*
>   2.2 Beyond or in addition to what has already been done: *this theme will be developed further in Chapter 6*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/further)

Comment: Hmm. Possibly but not necessarily! I think *further* is quite likely to be a discourse marker with an additive meaning. One of the clues is the position before the verb. So it could be "In this paper we analyse different tools for evaluating systems. We further describe the evaluation protocol" <-- Here *further* means *in addition to analysing different tools*, not *in addition to previously describing the protocol*. It's difficult to tell in the OP's example, without more context.

Answer (score 3):

Further is for metaphorical or figurative distance and is used in your example to state that now some more details or explanation will be provided regarding the evaluation protocol.